# Xamarin - White screen on ComposeEmail

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.essentials

Using a physical android device.

When ComposeEmail is called, the email client opens.
Once the email client opens, the app goes to white screen.

If I go back to the app it will stay on white screen.
If I hit the back button I will be brought to the login screen.

Does there need to be some session management here if an external app opens?

```
public async void SendEmail(EmailMessage message) { 
   await Xamarin.Essentials.Email.ComposeAsync(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. According to your description, you want to solve the problem of the white screen of the application. You can implement the operation you want in the **OnResume** method in the **App.xaml.cs** class, OnResume will be called when the app goes from the background to the app interface.
2. In Xamarin, the official support for using Email is provided. You can use **Xamarin.Essentials: Email**, and it will not show a white screen interface.Information about using Xamarin.Essentials: Email can be found at :[Xamarin.Essentials: Email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android).

Comment: The OnResume event is not triggered after the white screen is displayed. It looks like the app completely crashes after choosing an email client

Comment: Did you get an error message, have you tried using Xamarin.Essentials: Email?

Comment: No error and I am already using Xamarin.Essentials: Email, you can see in the example

Comment: Have you used a try/catch statement in your code. Has the program entered a catch statement?