# Xamarin - Android white screen when opening external app

Tags: xamarin.android

Related to this question but seems to be not related to ComposeEmail
[Xamarin - White screen on ComposeEmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311479/xamarin-white-screen-on-composeemail)

If I open an external app and return to the first app, I will have a white screen. No lifecycle events are triggered.

When I push the back button I will be brought to the login screen. App doesn't fully crash as the debugger stays attached. But no errors are shown

Comment: I had tried the ComposeEmail and it worked well. In addition, the white screen always shows when the app is not full started. And the login screen you sayed belong to the GEmail app or your app?

Comment: Is there any email app which the Xamarin.Essentials.Email supports on your phone?